# How handle with “use of closed network connection”

Tags: go

For a http ‘listenAndServe’ and ‘listener.close’, then it will trigger listener with this err “use of closed network connection”

I linked the issue, and there are example codes. I’m not sure how to solve this err in an elegant way.
Can someone help?

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/52480

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Basically `http.Server.Serve` makes the `net.Listener` passed to it run an endless loop calling [`accept(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/2/accept) on each iteration and once the call succeeds, make a `net.Conn` out of it and then proceed with handling a HTTP requets on that connection. When you close the listener, the `accept(2)` on which `http.Server.Serve` is currently blocked, exits with an error, and that error is then wrapped and returned from that method—exactly what you're observing.

Comment: The real question is: why are you closing the listener instead of the server itself (which will close the listener)? Won't that fulfill your needs?

Comment: That error is expected when you close a connection while in use. How do you want to handle it, and how would that be "elegant"?

Comment: An "elegant"—to a certain extent—way to check the error returned from `http.Server.Serve` would be to type-assert it to `*net.OpError` and then verify its `Op` field contains the string "accept"—naming the syscall which failed. You still won't assert that error is really "using of a closed network connection", but I think it'd be so close to the goal I'd call it a day. Still, I repeat this is not how you're supposed to roll; you should `Close` or `Shutdown` the server instead of the listener.

Comment: @kostix, 
Yeah, I think that I use the `close` wrong. As you said, I should use 'server.ShutDown' instead.

Comment: @JimB I think the point is that it is not really an error as it is expected, and we wouldn't want to pollute logging systems with expected errors